# Looking for a function to synchronise multiple nivo-sliders

Tags: jquery, slider, nivo-slider

My first time posting on stack overflow so i'm hoping someone will be able to give me a hand with this problem:

I have 3 nivo-sliders on a page, lined up horizontally. I would like them to be synchronised but more often then not they fall out of sync after a few seconds. This is the case when all sliders are initialised with this code:

```
    $(window).load(function() {
     $('#slider').nivoSlider({
      animSpeed:500,         
      pauseTime:3000,         
     });
    });
```

However, I figured that I could set one slider up like this and another two with the parameter:

```
    manualAdvance:true,
```

and then use:

```
    beforeChange: function(){},
```

on the first slider to control the other two - keeping them in sync. However... I'm not sure what function to use here in order to forward the other sliders and I have looked EVERYWHERE, I really appreciate your help with this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This doesnt seem to be implemented in the core of the Plugin

but you may add it yourself

in Nivo Slider v2.6 the uncompressed version at line 633 just below the function declaration of start and stop

```
// Start / Stop
this.stop = function(){
    if(!$(element).data('nivo:vars').stop){
        $(element).data('nivo:vars').stop = true;
        trace('Stop Slider');
    }
}

this.start = function(){
    if($(element).data('nivo:vars').stop){
        $(element).data('nivo:vars').stop = false;
        trace('Start Slider');
    }
}
```

you may add the folowing function

```
//Manually run the slider
this.run = function() {
        nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'next');
}
```

after incldueing the changed .js and maybe compress it yourself (http://javascriptcompressor.com/) you may use it like

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider().data('nivoslider').run();
```

put this in the right event and you should be done

Answer (score 0):

Setting the pause time and animSpeed should get your nivo sliders in sync I would have thought.

You say "more often then not they fall out of sync after a few seconds", is it possible you have pauseOnHover: true and you are hovering over them inadvertantly and they are getting out of sync. May be a silly question but this has happened to me.